# How to avoid looking as a slacker?

Tags: new-job, germany, new-hires

So I'm a recent graduate and my first job as a software developer in a German company will start in two weeks and I'm so excited about it. However I'm concerned about one little thing. The team has a daily meeting with our boss to explain what everyone did in front of everyone. I did a three days trial at the company and in my first three days I had to accomplish one task. The task was so easy but I was so nervous that I couldn't accomplish much of it. So in those daily meetings I always looked very unproductive and this is my main concern now.

My main concern is that I'm afraid that I may not be as good as my colleagues, most of them had practical education, while my education was mostly in research and now I'm a developer. So they might be able to be more productive programmers than I am. Maybe, I dunno. So my main concern now as I said is the fact that I could be not productive and that my colleagues might think that I'm a slacker or so.

My manager said that I will start working on small tasks to understand the code and such and then move on to bigger tasks.

My questions:

1- What makes someone a slacker in software development teams? i.e. suppose that I'm in fact slower than my colleagues in writing code and not as productive as them due to lack of experience, would they consider me a slacker?

2- If i'm in fact slower, is there something I can do to compensate for this?

3- If someone is slower than others due to lack of experience, would the manager consider that and give me time to catch to the experience of my peers?

4- Any other advise? It would be great if someone from the German software developers/managers here could answer this question.

I'm mostly concerned of the daily meetings when everyone will mention all those amazing tasks they accomplished but I will only mention probably couple tasks or so.

Comment: You'd ratherwrite bad code fast just so that you don't look like a slacker? Since you are starting with them, they are probably more interested that you don't do any damage. My attitude when I start any new job is that if I don't get fired within the first two weeks, I am golden :)

Comment: You are overthinking this. Millions of people go to work everyday and survive just fine, even in Germany I'm sure. Just relax, adapt to the situation as it comes, and be receptive to new ideas and people.

Comment: Easy: *Don't be a slacker*

Answer (score 14):

> So I'm a recent graduate and my first job as a software developer in a German company

The company that hired you knows that. Their expectations of you will be adjusted. You're not expected to churn out tons of code from day one don't worry.

> 1- What makes someone a slacker in software development teams? i.e. suppose that I'm in fact slower than my colleagues in writing code and not as productive as them due to lack of experience, would they consider me a slacker?

Being a 'slacker' isn't about being unproductive, it's about not being professional in how much effort you put into work. It's about not having work ethics. Typically a slacker will come in late or leave early, won't care too much about their profession and so on.

The fact you're slower than people because of lack of experience is expected, it means you're not as good of a programmer *which is perfectly OK* - they wouldn't expect anything different and there is no reason for them to consider you a slacker.

> 2- If i'm in fact slower, is there something I can do to compensate for this?

Work harder, and learn how to get things done quickly. There are a lot of resources on improving as a software developer online. Also, repeating myself from earlier being slower as a new junior employee is entirely anticipated on their end.

> I'm mostly concerned of the daily meetings when everyone will mention all those amazing tasks they accomplished but I will only mention probably couple tasks or so.

The goal of the meeting isn't to boast accomplishments - it's so everyone in the company knows what other people are doing so everyone has a good grip and if someone has domain knowledge or insights into someone else's work they have a chance to discover that and share them.